# When to use the required attribute vs the aria-required attribute for input elements?

Tags: html, accessibility, required, wai-aria, html-input

I'm trying to make a form accessible. Should I make my inputs have both `required` and `aria-required` attributes, or just one?

```
<label for="textbox1">Input</label>
<input id="textbox1" type="text" name="Text Box" required>
```

Or like this?

```
<label for="textbox1">Input</label>
<input id="textbox1" type="text" name="Text Box" aria-required="true">
```

Or like this?

```
<label for="textbox1">Input</label>
<input id="textbox1" type="text" name="Text Box" aria-required="true" required>
```

The article [*Accessible HTML5 Forms – Required Inputs*](http://john.foliot.ca/required-inputs/) claims it is best to implement both.

**EDIT: The above linked site is no longer active.**

Comment: Article link looks great, and answer depends on compatibility option that you search for. The widest range comes when you use both. You can also look https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-required_attribute

Answer (score 57, accepted):

When John Foliot wrote that article in 2012 it was very much true. You needed both.

Today that is no longer the case. I can take your example, put it [in a CodePen](http://s.codepen.io/aardrian/debug/NrbMYx), and check it in JAWS and NVDA (sorry, no VoiceOver today):

```
<label for="textbox1">Input</label>
<input id="textbox1" type="text" name="Text Box" required>
```

You will be happy to know that both NVDA and JAWS announce the field as required.

In short, you **do not** need `aria-required` any longer. Just use `required`.

You can read a bit more about the ARIA attributes you can dump in this article by Steve Faulkner (one of the editors of the ARIA spec) from 2015: http://html5doctor.com/on-html-belts-and-aria-braces/

Comment: See similar answer to related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38059140/when-to-use-the-disabled-attribute-vs-the-aria-disabled-attribute-for-html-eleme/38059790#38059790

Comment: `aria-required` may be useful if you want to avoid native browser validation.

Answer (score 4):

> HTML5 now has the required attribute, but aria-required is still
>   useful for user agents that do not yet support HTML5.

Ref: [Using the aria required attribute post on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-required_attribute)