# HTML: Voice Over users able to access disabled select box

Tags: javascript, html, voiceover, screen-readers

I want to create disabled select box for voice over users. I have this simple HTML. Select is disabled using disabled="disabled" and aria-disabled="true". But it is still accessible by Voice Over users.

Checked in MacOS (Chrome/Safari). VO reads Select as disabled. But I'm able to access it by clicking 'Ctrl+Option+Space'. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <label>Select</label>
        <select disabled="disabled" aria-disabled="true">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/acxksd1r/2/

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38059140/when-to-use-the-disabled-attribute-vs-the-aria-disabled-attribute-for-html-eleme it seems what you have done should, kind-of, work. Can you replace your select tag attributes with: `<select disabled>` (the setting of the attributes in not necessary, and aria-disabled is also not necessary).

Comment: @Polymer Removed disabled="disabled" and aria-disabled="true". And just added "disabled". It doesn't resolve my issue. http://jsfiddle.net/acxksd1r/7/

Comment: Does it actually read out the values in your select box or does it read out the word `dimmed`?