# How to add aria-required to Material-UI select component

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui, accessibility

I'm struggling with adding 'aria-required' property to Material-UI component.
Does anybody have experience with it ?
I didn't tried anything because the docs don't talk about it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do this?

```js
<Button aria-required="true" variant="contained" color="primary">
  Hello World
</Button>
```

If you have the attribute stored in a variable:

```js
const myAttributes = {
  "aria-required": "true"
};
return (
  <Button {...myAttributes} variant="contained" color="primary">
    Hello World
  </Button>
);
```

EDIT: To add the attribute to the `<Select />` component

```js
<Select
  // add the attribute to the container
  aria-required="true"
  // add the attribute to the input element
  inputProps={{
    "aria-required": "true"
  }}
>
  {...}
</Select>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64414078/how-to-add-aria-required-to-material-ui-select-component]

Comment: Hi, unfortunately your solution is not working for me. I'm trying to add aria-required to Select component.

Comment: I tried to add it directly to the component and to inputProps and they both not worked for me

Comment: @NetanelVaknin See my updated answer, if it doesn't work for you, please add the problematic code to the question and also your `@material-ui/core` version.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
My @material-ui/core version is 4.9.13 
I did exactly the way you sent over here and I can see that the attribute aria-required="true" is added when I inspect element in the browser. Anyway, my screen reader is not reading that for me.

Comment: I don't use screen reader so I don't know how to debug it besides inspecting the dom element. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37975985/9449426) answer to see if it can help you. @NetanelVaknin